# certificate cannot be used as an SSL server certificate

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I created a certificate using powershell command `New-SelfSignedCertificate`

and I was able to see the certificate in MMC\Certificate Personal store. I then moved it to the Trusted store to get rid of the warning message in the certificate. I exported the certificate so that I may import it in IIS. (the exported file has the PFX extension)

after providing the pass-phrase/password, i got the error:

"certificate cannot be used as an SSL server certificate"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The usage needs to be set to allow "Server" usage as well as "client" usage. I can't remember the powershell off the top of my head, but a quick google should do it.

Comment: According to https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/3274/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-powershell/, when you generate it it should show 'Server Authentication'

Comment: The actual PowerShell command you used is the key here. You have to generate a all -purpose certificate (without key usage restrictions) or a server certificate ("Server Authentication" purpose), or IIS Manager will reject it.